# Why does this function return a tuple?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, tuples

I have defined a fairly simple function that is having an unexpected output.  I'm using Steam game reviews and want to use a function to narrow the scope based on game title.  This works fine:

```
one_game = games[games['title'] == "Robocraft"]
```

The output is a dataframe just like the original.  However, when I try to make a function (by passing the same game name as an argument) to slice the dataframe as follows:

```
def slice(game):
    out = games[games['title'] == game],
    return(out)
```

I get a tuple that is "[362 rows x 5 columns],)" instead of a dataframe.  Is that because of the return command or is that just something that happens when you use a user defined function?

This seems like all I would need to do is convert the tuple back to a dataframe.  However, I can't even do that!  When I do, I get this error:

> "ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 362, 5)"

How can I get a dataframe as my output?

Thank you!

Comment: Check the comma at the end of the line. Commas make tuples.

Comment: @BENY There's no difference between `out` and `(out)`. Parentheses don't make tuples.

Comment: @fchisowsky Didn't you see Mark's suggestion? That's the solution.

Comment: The question doesn't have anything to do with Pandas or dataframes; and to do such a "conversion" would require you to first properly understand the actual value you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma at the end of the first line of your function is the problem. It wraps the preceding value in a tuple, see:

```
>>> 1
1

>>> 1,
(1,)

>>> a = 1
>>> type(a)
1

>>>> a = 1,
>>> type(a)
tuple
```

So just remove that comma, (and the parentheses after `return`, because `return` is a keyword, not a function):

```
def slice(game):
    out = games[games['title'] == game]
    return out
```